# In Javassist, is return order guaranteed?

Tags: java, reflection, javassist

Javassist's `CtClass` has a few methods, such as `getFields()` and `getMethods()`. I was wondering if these methods offer any guarantee as to their ordering.

Specifically, I'd like to know if using `getFields()` on a class will produce and array of `CtFields` where the first field in the array is the first field declared in the file and so forth. So, is this order guaranteed? If not, is there anything that can offer this guarantee? The javadocs give no information on the matter. I've tried annotations that carry order (e.g. `@X(1) private int first;`), but it'd be easier if I could reflect this sort of thing without the need for annotations?

If it's still not clear, I'd like something like:

```
public class Class {
    public int x;
    public float y;
    public Object z;
}
```

to produce an array of `CtFields` specifically and consistently ordered `x, y, z`.

Comment: I doubt the compiler makes any guarantee that the order they are put into the class file is the same as the lexical order in which they appear in the source code, although I could be wrong. If the compiler doesn't guarantee that, there is no way Javassist or any other bytecode library (or even Java reflection) could make such a guarantee. Why do you care about the order? Can you avoid that, or use any canonical ordering e.g., sorting by name?

Comment: I can solve the particular problem I'm working on through any number of solutions, but it would dramatically increase the flexibility of the system being designed if I could use source ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at one of the implementations of `CtClass`, like `CtClassType`, you will see that `getMethods()` is implemented that way:

```
public CtMethod[] getMethods() {
    HashMap h = new HashMap();
    getMethods0(h, this);
    return (CtMethod[])h.values().toArray(new CtMethod[h.size()]);
}
```

According to the [`HashMap` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

So, you have absolutely no guarantee in what order you will get the methods.

---

For the fields, the code is a lot more complicated, but it seems that the raw class file is read as an `InputStream`:

```
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(
                                     new FileInputStream(args[0]));
ClassFile w = new ClassFile(in);
```

And the fields are created as they are read from this stream:

```
fields = new ArrayList();
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    addField2(new FieldInfo(cp, in));
```

So, the fields are created in the order they are in the class file.

However, reading the [JVM Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.1) and the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-13.html), I see no reference to the fields order in the generated class; this sentence from the Java Specification even seems to indicate that the fields order is not important:

> Using their scheme, here is a list of some important binary compatible changes that the Java programming language supports:
>   [...]
>    Reordering the fields, methods, or constructors in an existing type declaration.

So I think that you have absolutely no guarantee on the fields order too.

---

I tried to run `javassist.tools.Dump` on a test class I created with a large number of fields and methods, and it seems that fields and methods are printed in the source order, but I still think that nothing **guarantee** it.